# Why are certificates secure in azure key vault?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, secret-key

Any one who can hack into my code and get the client id, tenant id and cert thumbprint can access the secrets stored in my key vault. So what’s the difference between this and just storing the secret values directly in my code where any one who hacks into my code could read?

Answer (score 0):

Even if someone was able to get that info, your vault will still be secure because in order to access your Key Vault and view the contents inside, a user, app, or identity will need to be added to your Key Vault's management plane (RBAC), and data plane (access policies) to view anything within your vault.

Therefore, if a user has a TenantID they still won't have access to your AKV unless they have the credentials of a user, app, or identity that has the correct RBAC and access policies permissions.

For more info: [Management plane and Azure RBAC Data plane and access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#management-plane-and-azure-rbac)

Comment: so all the creds I need to access the key vault are stored in my code (client and tenant id of my azure AD app registration and the thumbprint of a self signed cert I created and uploaded to the key vault which is connected to the app registration via access policy), if a hacker were to get those and then create his own piece of software using those creds to get the secret, how does azure know that his machine lacks correct rbac or access policy permissions? If I logged on to some one else computer and engineered an app with those credentials, would I be blocked from accessing the key vault?

Comment: @KyleTrent My recommendations for your scenario:

1) If your code is hosted in Azure, then move to MSI.

2) If your code is hosted on-prem, then use a client certificate for AAD authentication to obtain an access token.  Import the client certificate with a non-exportable private key.

3) Lock down the access policies to only specific information that the clients require. Since AKV uses all-or-nothing permissions to objects (secret,key,cert), use separate key vaults if finer granularity is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For applications hosted in Azure, using [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) is preferred. This is a separate principal where a password is never made available to even steal or leak.

If you use the [DefualtAzureCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential) in the Azure SDKs, you can better configure your vault for development and production environments. You can give limited permissions to AAD users, who can log in via Visual Studio, Azure CLI, Az PowerShell Module, and more. Without modifying the code, your application can rely on Managed Identity with its own set of permissions. For example, maybe you use different vaults for production and development configured by a setting where Managed Identity has read access to secrets/keys, but your devs don't - not in the production vault. Role-based Access Control is also coming to Managed HSM (a more secure hardware-based Key Vault) to have principal granularity even in the same vault.

Service principals using environment variables can be used in lieu of Managed Identity but should be reserved only for your production environment, ideally. Devs could also have one, but that probably means sharing of client IDs and secrets, which provides little to no mitigation if someone leaves or information is leaked - no easy mitigation, anyway.

Comment: I looked into managed identity but it seemed as though I needed to deploy the database and app to azure in order to use it. My data base and server is a machine which I rdp into and host with iss, not the azure cloud. Is it still possible to use managed identity without hosting the database and app from the Azure cloud?